# How do you print out values one at a time using collections.shuffle in an arraylist with loops?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

We are stuck while working on a bingo program we are trying to create. We are amateur programers and we were able to output randomized values with numbers, but the when we output these numbers, it prints all of the numbers.  Is there a way to print the numbers one at a time, without repeating while keeping track of the numbers already printed?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandonNumberGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Integer> RandomNumsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        RandomNumsList.add(1);

        ... //we added index numbers 1-75, but we didn't want to take up too much 
                    //space so we put this space to replace 2-74

                RandomNumsList.add(75);

        Collections.shuffle(RandomNumsList);
        String letter;
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index<RandomNumsList.size(); index++)
        {
            int x=0;
            x=RandomNumsList.get(index);
            if (x>0 && x<=15)
            { 
                letter=("B");
            System.out.println (letter+x);

            }
            if (x>15 && x<=30)
            { 
                letter=("I");
                System.out.println (letter+x);
            }
            if (x>30 && x<=45)
            { 
                letter=("N");
                System.out.println (letter+x);
            }
            if (x>45 && x<=60)
            { 
                letter=("G");
                System.out.println (letter+x);
            }
            if (x>60 && x<=75)
            { 
                letter=("O");
                System.out.println (letter+x);
            }               
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: You could add a new collection with the called numbers for tracking (and bingo validation later on) and remove the original number from your randomized collection after placing it in the new collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an issue:

```
ArrayList<Integer> RandomNumsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
RandomNumsList.add(1);

//we added index numbers 1-75, but we didn't want to take up too much 
//space so we put this space to replace 2-74

RandomNumsList.add(75);
```

Fix by initializing the numbers with a for loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer> RandomNumsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <=75; i++) {
    RandomNumsList.add(i);
}
```

Now, keep your printing loop in check with a Scanner and add already used numbers to an array list.  Press enter for the next number:

```
    Collections.shuffle(RandomNumsList);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> numsAlreadyUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String letter;
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index<RandomNumsList.size(); index++) {
        System.out.println("Press enter for the next number!");
        scan.nextLine()
        int x=RandomNumsList.get(index);
        numsAlreadyUsed.add(x);

        if (x>0 && x<=15) { 
            letter=("B");
        } else if (x>15 && x<=30) { 
            letter=("I");
        } else if (x>30 && x<=45) {
            letter=("N");
        }else if (x>45 && x<=60) { 
            letter=("G");
        }else if (x>60 && x<=75) { 
            letter=("O");
        }
        // no need to repeat this line in every branch of the if statement!
        System.out.println (letter+x);
    }
```

Alternatively, any number in the original array list below the index has already been used.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

For a start, i've simplified adding the numbers to the list for you.
Then, as it goes through the list of letters, when i matches, it stores the letter, and removes the number from the list. It will only match the letters once, and will stop once it has matched each letter once.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> RandomNumsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++) {
        RandomNumsList.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(RandomNumsList);
    String letters = "";

    while (RandomNumsList.size() > 0 && letters.length() < 5) {
        int x = 0;
        x = RandomNumsList.get(0);
        if (x > 0 && x <= 15 && !letters.contains("B")) {
            letters += ("B");
            System.out.println(letters + x);
        } else if (x > 15 && x <= 30 && !letters.contains("I")) {
            letters += ("I");
            System.out.println(letters + x);
        } else if (x > 30 && x <= 45 && !letters.contains("N")) {
            letters += ("N");
            System.out.println(letters + x);
        } else if (x > 45 && x <= 60 && !letters.contains("G")) {
            letters += ("G");
            System.out.println(letters + x);
        } else if (x > 60 && x <= 75 && !letters.contains("O")) {
            letters += ("O");
            System.out.println(letters + x);
        } else {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        RandomNumsList.remove(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think he's trying to get the string "Bingo." It seems to me that he is trying to create a generator to simulate picking bingo balls.

Comment: If I have gone too far, let me know and I can strip out some of the extra bits. Was trying to guess what you wanted it to do based on the existing code.